# How does django UpdateView find a html form? (name convention)

Tags: django, naming-conventions

I am following a django tutorial and everything is working, but I don't understand how this class, in views.py, find the album_form.html if I didn't pass any parameters of the path/name.

```
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model = Album
    fields = ['artist' , 'album_title' , 'genre' , 'album_logo']
```

The html name is album_form.html and works fine, but if I change to somethingelse_form.html it doesn't work anymore. From where django identifies that it have to use 'album' instead of 'somethingelse'? What is the name convention?

Its not from urls.py, because mine is this:

```
url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `CreateView` class.

```
class CreateView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseCreateView):
    template_name_suffix = '_form'
```

As you can see it has class attribute `template_name_suffix` which is used in
`SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin` when `get_template_names` is being called.

Here is the pattern that is used for constructing value of `template_name`.

```
`<app_label>/<model_name><template_name_suffix>.html`
```

That's why it renders `album_form.html` without specifying `template_name` in your view.

Also there is an explanation in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview).

Answer (score 0):

for update template do following: **album_update_form.html** in your template/yourappname folder.
In your update class do this:

```
template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```